# TextView does not wrap content when the text wraps in second line

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-textview-autosize

In the following why does the `TextView` have extra space when the text wraps to the second line (highlighted with the yellow box in the image bellow)? How can I remove that?

[image]

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/green"
>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="THIS IS FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
                android:background="@color/red"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"

    >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="THIS IS FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
                android:background="@color/red"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There's nothing you can do. The textview first tries to grow as wide as it can in order to fit your text, and then when that isn't enough it does line wrapping. But it doesn't then re-size itself back down to fit the wrapped text.

Comment: @BenP.: Really? Is there a way to do it programmatically? The issue with this is that in such case the layout does not appear centered anymore due the textview extra space. Technically it is centered but visually that is not apparent

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to achieve what you want without re-implementing your own text view. You could apply `gravity="center_horizontal"` to your textview, but then you wouldn't have left-justified text across multiple lines.

Comment: try to set                 android:layout_width="0dp" and             android:layout_weight="1" for text view

Comment: @Jim Ben P is right , there is nothing you can do except resizing the text size

Comment: @ismailalaoui: Resize the text? Why?

Comment: to make it fit in a single line

Comment: @BenP.:Any tip how to do it with custom textview?

Comment: Nope. That's way above my pay grade.

Comment: @BenP.: What if I used another parent layout instead of Linear? E.g. ConstraintLayout. Could that somehow help?

Comment: If you really want to resize your text (I don't think it is the best solution) you can check the TextView property: android:autoSizeTextType and set it to uniform. Other options you can check: scrollHorizontally and singleLine. Or if you want to truncate the text use ellipsize.

Comment: @Lucas:Both scrollHorizontally and singleLine set?

Comment: Yes, Both attributes set to true. But it would be better if you edit the question showing your real situation and not a test with any text view with any content, so we can give you a better advice depending on the situation. By the way, try to use Constraint Layout instead of using nested Linear Layouts (it is more efficient). In the editors view, there is an option called "Convert LinearLayout to ContraintLayout", it may help you as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Could try some brute force. Split the text into rows first. Loop them, measure the width, if not exceed textView's width, append to a string builder, if larger than textView's width, measure character by character, if not exceed, append to string builder, else append a "\n" to string builder. Get the string by this builder and set it to textView.

Answer (score 0):

the actual reason for that is you have given  **android:layout_weight** property to the LinearLayout. According to that Seperation of Layout take place remove android:layout_weight and check as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/green">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="THIS IS FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
                android:background="@color/red"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="THIS IS FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
                android:background="@color/red"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```